# how to make network calls with react native using oauth 1.0?

Tags: react-native, woocommerce-rest-api

I am working on react native app for android platform. Basically, I want to connect backend  apis made by woocommerce platform, and for that I have to use oauth1.0 authentication loop (with `consumer key` and `consumer secret`)to get data. So, is there any possibility that I can make network requests with fetch or any other library in react native?

Comment: did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest` and `WebSocket` on React Native, and of course, any library that builds on top of those, such as [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios). Have a look at the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.38/docs/network.html#networking).

Comment: I want to pass consumer key and consumer secret to this url :  http://quflip.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products, so how should i pass them if i use axios?

Comment: Not sure about how OAuth works. I just read [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests) that the authorization keys should go into the header of the request. If that is the case, it is rather simple, you just have to set the header as done in [this example](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config).